# Referencing a variable outside the Python class in the same script gives an error

Tags: python

I define `arr = []` before anything else. Why do I get an error when my class references it?

```
arr = []

class BST:
  key = 0
  left = None
  right = None
  height = 0
  index = 0


  def __init__(self):
    height = 0

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.key)

  def populate(self):
     print("populating")
     print(self.key)

     if (self.left != None):
       arr = arr + [self.left.populate()]

     if (self.right != None):
       arr = arr + [self.right.populate()]

     return self.key

m1 = BST()
m1.key = 3
m2 = BST()    
m2.key = 5
m1.left = m2

print(m1.left != None)

m3 = BST()
m3.key = 6
m2.left = m3

res = m1.populate()
print(res)
```

```
~/py/python bst.py
True
populating
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bst.py", line 41, in <module>
    res = m1.populate()
  File "bst.py", line 22, in populate
    arr = arr + [self.left.populate()]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'arr' referenced before assignment
~/py/
```

Comment: You need to declare `global arr` inside the method that uses `arr`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `global` in the scope of function

```
arr = []

class BST:
    key = 0
    left = None
    right = None
    height = 0
    index = 0


    def __init__(self):
        height = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.key)

    def populate(self):
        global arr
        print("populating")
        print(self.key)

        if (self.left != None):
            arr = arr + [self.left.populate()]

        if (self.right != None):
            arr = arr + [self.right.populate()]

        return self.key

m1 = BST()
m1.key = 3
m2 = BST()    
m2.key = 5
m1.left = m2

print(m1.left != None)

m3 = BST()
m3.key = 6
m2.left = m3

res = m1.populate()
print(res)

True
populating
3
populating
5
populating
6
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in these lines:

```
if (self.left != None):
   arr = arr + [self.left.populate()]

 if (self.right != None):
   arr = arr + [self.right.populate()]
```

You think that the assignment to a global variable `arr` should be made. But the fact is, when Python compiles the body of the function `def populate()`, it decides that `arr` is a local
variable because it is assigned within the function. The generated bytecode reflects this
decision and will try to fetch `arr` from the local environment. Later, when the call `m1.populate()` is made, the body of `populate()` trying to fetch the value of local variable `arr` and discovers that `arr` is unbound.
Your code will work if you will try not to override `arr` but to extend it:

```
 if (self.left != None):
   arr.append(self.left.populate())

 if (self.right != None):
   arr.append(self.right.populate())
```

Comment: Why `extend` with one item when you can `append`?

Comment: list.append() will return you new list object when extend just updates the list (initial list would be mutated).

Comment: No. That's wrong. That applies to numpy arrays not lists.

Comment: It's easy to check. Try to compare two objects: `l = []; a = l.append(2); l is a`. The result is `False` that means that a new object was generated. On the other hand `l.extend([1])` returns None (but not a new list object) that means that object was changed in place.

Comment: Do `print(a)` after your assignment `a = l.append(2)`. `list.append` works in-place, just like `list.extend`, no need to assign anything :P

Comment: `a = l.append(2)` not valid expression. `List` don't have return type therefore you cannot assign values while using append func

Answer (score 0):

You can import the main module, or make it global inside

```
arr = []

class BST:
    key = 0
    left = None
    right = None
    height = 0
    index = 0


    def __init__(self):
        height = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.key)

    def populate(self):
        import __main__
        print("populating")
        print(self.key)

        if (self.left != None):
           __main__.arr = arr + [self.left.populate()]

        if (self.right != None):
           __main__.arr = arr + [self.right.populate()]

        return self.key

m1 = BST()
m1.key = 3
m2 = BST()    
m2.key = 5
m1.left = m2

print(m1.left != None)

m3 = BST()
m3.key = 6
m2.left = m3

res = m1.populate()
print(res)

True
populating
3
populating
5
populating
6
3
```